# ASP.NET Web API breaking Repository/Services pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to building web APIs and have reached a point where I could use some direction. So lets say for example that I have a `Product` model and a `Attachment` model which look something like this:

```
 public class Product
 {
     public Product()
     {
        Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
     }
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
 }

 public class Attachment
 {
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Notice that the `Product` model has a property list of type `Attachment`. Is is bad practice to utilize the `AttachmentRepository` to fill this property when I am initializing the `Property` object in the `ProductRepository` class?

So in the `ProductRepository` I would do something like this:

```
Product product = new Product
{
    ID = SomeId,
    Name = SomeName
    Attachments = AttachmentRepository.GetAttachments(SomeName)
};
```

Is this poor design and I am approaching this incorrectly? I am not planning to create a Controller for `Attachment` since there would be no use case for getting an attachment without the context of a `Product`.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or some other ORM?

Comment: No Entity Framework here, just standard ASP.NET Web API 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I am not planning to create a Controller for Attachment since there would be no use case for getting an attachment without the context of a Product."

How about the inverse? Would you ever want to get the product without Attachments?

**I find methods that try to do too much not as reusable**, because if I am getting a large number of products and am not interested in attachments, I don't want the overhead of also getting attachments for all of those products.  I then regret the design(whether it was mine or a colleague's), adding a new method just to get Products.

In my controller I would have the call to GetProduct and then a call to GetAttachments.  This would allow you to mix-match these as needed.

Another approach would be to do this in the Products repository, have a method that gets just products(GetProducts), and another GetProductsWithAttachments method that calls GetProducts and also calls GetAttachments.  Or you could of course have a boolean parameter for `, includeAttachments = false)`.  I don't like my DB layer getting that messy.  I let the Controller be the place to pull it all together.

I would also probably not even have Attachments property in Products model, but instead have a ProductResponseModel specific to the controller that is the analogy of a ViewModel.  It would be the one with both the product information and the Attachments property, and you would populate it from the results of calling the two seperate Repository methods.

If you do it all at the DB layer, and your Product model from the DB layer has an Attachments property that is only populated when you call GetProductsWithAttachments, then your Product model is *half filled*.  **Add many other similar properties over time, and you've got a really confusing model because sometimes only some of its properties are populated based on which method of the repository you called.** Developers have to start digging into the repo methods to figure out what populates what.  If you add Promotions to a Product will you have a GetProductWithAttachments, GetProducts, GetProductWithPromotions, GetProductWithAttachmentsAndPromotions?  You can begin to see how this can get out of hand, and some default parameters would be better if you really want to bake this into your repository.  However:

### Recommended: Composition in the Controller

That's why my preference is to let the controller orchestrate the whole thing. Call repo methods separately within the controller.  Not sure if your using a REST style or what in your Web API controllers, so just consider this pseudo code:

```
public class ProductController: ApiController
{
  public ProductResponseModel Get(int productId) 
  {
     var model = new ProductResponseModel{
        Product = ProductRepository.Get(productId);
     };
     model.Attachments = AttachmentRepository.GetList(model.Product.Name);

     // I could have flattened out the Product into its properties instead of having a model.Product,
     // but that can be a maintenance problem and requires something like AutoMapper to manage well
     return model;
  }

}

public class ProductResponseModel {
  public Product Product {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Attachment> Attachments {get;set;}
}
```

The ProductResponseModel is an example of composition.  It creates loose coupling with the DB layer, so you are free to mix and match, i.e. **compose** models of what data you need for each API controller.  The ProductResponseModel itself is not very reusable, maybe only within that controller.  Another controller that needs a different combination of Product data will have its own SomethingResponseModel and call seperate Repository methods to populate it.  **Even though we don't get to reuse our *ResponseModels, that's not a big loss because they are simple POCOs.  Getting reuse out of our repo methods is more important, and saving them from becoming more complicated than they need to be.**  Additionally we still have your simple model such as `Product` and `Attachment` that are part of the repository layer, so that everyone calling the repo is speaking the same language and using the same common types.  So don't make the mistake of having your Repo layer return a ProductResponseModel.  It's your controller's job to take the `Product` and populate the `ProductResponseModel`.

I use the naming convention *ResponseModel because if I have a complex parameter for the action method also, then there is a *RequestModel as well.  I.e. Request/Response.  And if I have an API method that is more RPC style than REST style, such as maybe ProductController.DiscontinueDistribution its return might be very specialized and so I'd have a ProductDiscontinueDistributionResponseModel.  Still these are all simple POCOs just like ViewModels in MVC.

Comment: in the case that I call `GetProductsWithAttachments` from the `ProductController`, will I still be going cross Repo into the `AttachmentRepository`? Also if I do not get attachments for my `Product` object is it standard to have a property as null? (Attachments property in this case)

Comment: @user2596756 Yes, GetProductsWithAttachments would call GetProducts of the same repo, and then GetAttachments to the other repo.  All of my models are initialized with an empty list in the model's constructor, so that you don't have to constantly check for null after retrieving results.  This is why I prefer to do the cross repo calls from the controller, and have a model specific to that controller with the Attachments property, so that I don't have "half filled" models coming from the DB layer.

Comment: @user2596756 I have update the question to elaborate more. Sorry to ramble.  Certainly this is just one approach and others might have a vastly different approach.

Comment: @AaronLS (Possibly tangential to the discussion) - So in this instance you've put the logic that getting a product also retrieves the attachments in the controller and left the repository layer mostly ignorant about the idea that "we get attachments when we get products".  In the same way, if this is a POST or PUT situation where "we flip a bit on a product when we add/modify an attachment to indicate product X has a new/changed attachment", this logic should be part of that POST/PUT controller action?  That's what I *think* should be the case.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @AaronLS I guess what I'm asking here is "is the controller action the right place to enforce the idea that "I flip the bit on the product when I add/change an attachment.", which ultimately ends up (probably) being two repository calls to update two tables in a DB (products and attachments).  maybe that is clearer.

Comment: @itsmatt Retrieving data often deals with creating compositions of many objects and related objects, sometimes flattening out nested lists, etc. When you start talking about updating data though, usually you think in terms of a transaction. If adding an attachment flips a bit on a related object, that needs to be ACID compliant and occur within a transaction. You could do this in the controller action, but tier'd or onion architectures usually have a business layer between controller/repository such as `AttachmentsService.AddAttachment` that performs both operations in a transaction.

Comment: Either way, and depending on the capabilities of your ORM, you'd probably retrieve the product entity from the repo, flip the bit, and add the new attachment directly that entity reference, then call some sort of SaveChanges on the entity or repository.  Some ORMs provide direct update capabilities that would allow you to issue an update and insert directly without first retrieving the entity, given that you know the entity ID, and sometimes that's hard to expose from a repo pattern, so your busienss layer uses the ORM directly as-needed instead of the repo for these few special cases.

Answer (score 2):

If your not using EF or another ORM, then your `Product` object probably shouldn't contain a list of `Attachment` objects -- that should be a construction of (like @AaronLS said) some form of DTO akin to a viewmodel in MVC.

Something like:

```
public class DTOProductAttachment
{
    Product Product { get; set; }
    List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }

    public DTOProductAttachment(int id, string name)  // <-- Product ID, Product Name
    { 
        Product = ProductRepository.GetProduct(id); // <-- Product ID
        Attachments = AttachmentRepository.GetAttachmentsByProductName(name); // <-- Product Name, or ID or whatever joins your tables
    }; 
}
```

... And I think the importance here is, your "objects" `Product` and `Attachment` should be reflective of your database design. Your repositories should act in a way that is intuitive of your architecture.

For example, the `AttachmentsRepository.GetAttachmentsByProductName()` method above is completely intuitive if `Name` (Product name) is a foreign key on your `Attachments` table (probably should be Product.ID but I'm running with your example above.)

But, these decisions are relative to your design requirements/goals. For example, if an `Attachment` object had a one to many relationship with another object, let's say `AttachmentChild`, then it would be reasonable to assume you might want to select all of the `AttachmentChild` objects by `Product` Name or ID.

... In this case, adding a method like `AttachmentChildRepository.GetAttachmentsByProductName()` seems a little fishy.

For salience, you might include the `Product` Name (or ID) on the `AttachmentChild` object, even though it's not technically necessary.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I had similar thoughts about the retrieval by Name but didn't want to sidetrack. We usually use optional params that are well named `AttachmentRepository.Get(int? id = null, int? productId = null, string productName)` but it requires certain techniques for querying these conditionally (and I do **not** mean dynamic SQL).